# Netbean does not find library

Tags: java, swing, libraries, steelseries

[image]

I've added jar file but it seems the IDE did not find it. Got any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must download this jar not the sources
unzip and you add to your project libraries

[SteelSeries](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/SteelSeries/SteelSeries-3.9.5.jar.zip)

[image]